# Preserve file name Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Is it possible to convert a PDF file and use the same name name for the output as the input PDF ?

I'm aware that there are work arounds by doing it a separate rename command. But I'm trying to figure out if this can be done with GS.

Right now I'm able to change the PDF version by doing this:

```
gswin32c -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
         -sOutputFile=a.pdf -dBATCH b.pdf
```

However the input file and outfile name have to be different, if I do something like this...

```
gswin32c -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
         -sOutputFile=b.pdf -dBATCH b.pdf
```

...it doesn't work.

I assume that internally something get's messed up when the file tries to overwrite itself.

Is there any way to get around this using Ghostscript only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use the same file name for input and output PDF when you process it with Ghostscript (unless you use a different *directory path* for the output as compared to the input).

Answer (score 4):

On linux you can use a buffer. I use the linux tool `sponge` (part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)) to achieve this.

This works for me to reduce the file size for example:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=- big.pdf | sponge big.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is forcing overwriting the original file:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=temp.pdf file.pdf; mv -f temp.pdf file.pdf
```

You can combine these cammands for example inside one line in exec(); for PHP.